# How to set fixed width for UILabel to let other UIViews make constraint to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode7

I need to use two labels and one slider to display as player progress. In my case, 1st label was constrained to left of container, 2nd label to right of container, and the slider was constrain to those labels.
[image: Player progress]

My problem is that, while those two labels change their text, their width also change, so the slider also change its position since it was constrained to the labels. How to solve this problem?

Note: this problem happens when I updated to xcode 7.

Comment: Are you laying out these views in a storyboard or in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the width of both the labels and use minimum font size. Now put the constraints on the slider relative to the labels. Now the slider will be fixed. Just the font size of labels will change accordingly.

Comment: It can solve my problem. However, I still miss the way it works in previous version of xcode.